# Sorted() (Timsort) time complexity with lambda function as key

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, timsort

If I have the function
`sorted(points, key=lambda point: point[axis])`, is the time complexity still O(nlogn)?

I know that `sorted()` uses Timsort which has this Big-O time complexity for the average case but I am not sure how the lambda function adds to that. Returning a value is O(1) but this should be called for every element, so *n* times.

Does that mean that the time complexity is O(n) + O(nlogn)?

Comment: if `point[axis]` is constant time, then yes. it will essentially do `map(keyfunc, iterable)`

Comment: `O(n) + O(n log(n)) = O(n log(n))`